# Clipboard manager(s) not pasting

Tags: gnome, clipboard

I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04. I have tried two clipboard managers -- Diodon and an [extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/779/clipboard-indicator/) from Gnome.
They both copy as they should but I can't get them to paste. When I used Diodon in 12.04, I only needed to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> and click on the text to be copied. It don't work here.
Any idea why not?

Comment: Sounds to me like you're describing the diodon pop-up dialog, not the "paste". Is that right?

Comment: https://esite.ch/2015/07/using-custom-shortcuts-of-de-as-diodon-hotkey/

Comment: No, the pop-up works. It has all the copied text in it. It's just when I click on a line of text nothing happens.

Comment: The keyboard shortcut works just fine. Everything works fine until I go to paste. The it doesn't paste when I click on the line of text.

Comment: Select the text, then `Ctrl` + `C` for copy, and `Ctrl` + `V` for paste works for me in Xubuntu 16.04. You need to use `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `V` ONLY in Terminal apps. Because `Ctrl` + `V` is assigned to another command in Terminal.

Comment: Then I don't need the clipboard mgr. I could just use [Ctrl]+C and [Ctrl]+V. I would like it as I had it before ... [Ctrl]+[Shift]+V (shortcut already working), then click on line of text I want and it pastes. It did it just like in 12.04. OR, with Diodon, clicking of the icon still doesn't paste anything (though the pop-up window comes up).

Comment: Diodon is no longer supported, please install glipper from software center, works perfect.

Comment: I installed _Glipper_ but still the same: I can copy it to the clipboard but when I call the clipboard, _[Ctrl]+[Alt]+C_ , the clipboard pops up but, when I click on the text I want, it doesn't copy it to the document.

Comment: I can copy & paste w/o the clipboard. I just wanted to be able to access the history, etc. I have now installed GPaste and just use "Paste" in the right click menu. I still can't get anything to paste by clicking on the text in the clipboard utility but I guess I'll have to live with it. Thanks for the help though.

Comment: I have now installed Ubuntu 14.04. (I had far too many problems with 16.04.) But I still have the same problem.

If I highlight something and then go to gedit, press the middle mouse button, its pastes what I copy. The same for the terminal (pressing [Ctrl]+[Shift]+middle button). However, I can't get a clipboard manager to work, and I can't copy to a Wine-based program using either method (which I previously could do, using Ubuntu 12.04).

Any ideas? Could it have something to do with the kernel? I was running 3.x in 12.04; I am now running 4.2.0-42-generic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. Just for the record, in case anyone else has the same problem (using Diodon):

Open the dconf Editor

```
net
 |-- launchpad
        |-- diodon
               |-- clipboard
```

- makes sure "`instant paste`" is checked.

It works fine now. Thanks for the help.